# TypeError: DataType string for attr 'Tlabels' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I need help in training a tensorflow model. I just started using the Google Cloud Platform and is trying to train my own model with my own dataset.

Below is my code so far

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import h5py

# Datasets
training_set1 = h5py.File('/Users/Fang/workspace/keras_project/for_google-ml/trainer/11_type.h5', 'r')
output_set1 = open("/Users/Fang/workspace/keras_project/for_google-ml/trainer/output_type.txt", "r")

X = training_set1['the_data'][:]
Y = output_set1.read().split(',')

feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=2)]

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[500, 100, 11],
                                        n_classes=3,
                                        model_dir="/tmp/the_model")

classifier.fit(X, Y, steps=2000)
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(X, Y)["accuracy"]
print("Accuracy: %.2f".format(accuracy_score))
```

And I got error like this when running it locally.

```
TypeError: DataType string for attr 'Tlabels' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```

My `training_set` consists of following data saved as `the_data` dataset in hdf5 format. It has multiple array of 500 number each. Example :

```
[[12.424, 384.742,...],
 [3492.293, 349,..,...],
 [...,...,...],
  ...
  ...
 [...]]
```

My `output_set` is a text file with the following 500 data

```
aaa,aaa,aaa,...,bbb,bbb,bbb,...ccc,ccc,...,kkk,kkk,kkk
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does your hd5f file contain the data in the right format? There are several viewers available.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `right format for hdf5` ? Before, I train this with using Keras and everything is good without error.